gparted create partition table lost partitions can't boot into windows
I stupidly used gparted went create partition and lost my partitions.
I had multiple windows partitions. I have used testdisk and recovered the partitions although I am unable to boot into them. I used aoime portion manager to rebuild MBR but I get blue screen file missing winload.exe
I had multiple windows 10 partitions on this drive.
Can I use another 3rd party Linux bootloader to boot into these partitions?
Thank you
